# Why can't emacs find the haskell-mode package?

Tags: haskell, emacs, intero

The error I am currently getting is:

```
File error: http://melpa.org/packages/haskell-mode-20161110.316.tar, Not found
```

when installing [intero](https://commercialhaskell.github.io/intero/). How do I go about fixing this?

Thank you!

Comment: It installed fine for me. Current version from `package-list-packages` is intero-20170221.931, which looks newer than your reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
(package-refresh-contents)
```

In case you do not have melpa, since it is not available on the elpa repository:

```
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                     ("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                     ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Comment: Very helpful. Grazie mille!